# How to read .Net textbox populated with jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net

I'm trying to read the text of a .Net control. I show the control in a jquery modal popup. then I submit the form with a .Net button. When I try to read the control server side, there is nothing in its text property. How do I read the textbox control that has been populated within a jquery modal dialog? I will certainly try alternatives to what I am doing...using .Net and jquery.

page:

```
<img id="divTestQ" src="assets/images/edit_icon.gif" alt="Add Comments" />
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="divTest" title="Program Discipline" style="text-align: left;">
    <asp:TextBox id="test" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="30" style="width: 100%;"     
        runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<asp:button id="btnSubmit" text="label" runat="server" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("#divTest").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    width: 500,
    height: 480,
    modal: true
    });

$("#divTestQ").click(function () {
    $("#divTest").dialog("open");
    return false;
    });
```

Code Behind:

```
String textBox = test.Text;       //Nothing

TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_test");   //Also Nothing
```

Comment: Is there nothing for the text property or is it not finding the control at all?  Please post the relevant code

Comment: `HTML` + `JS` + `JQuery` + `.net` codes please!

Comment: As far as jQuery is concerned, there is no such thing as a .Net button, or a .Net control. There is only HTML. How your serverside code models these is irrelevant to the jQuery code.

Comment: Code posted. I accidentally hit enter before I was finished...and you guys are very fast at responding :)

Comment: @AbeMiessler can you please help with this. The code is posted. I read the post from DJH, but still cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the textbox is now outside of the form.  The way around this is to attach the modal to the form when opening it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divTest").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            width: 500,
            height: 480,
            modal: true,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
     });
```

Comment: I'm still not able to do a findcontrol and get a reference to the textbox. Is there a step I am missing when using findcontrol? I have my textbox wrapped in a div and the findcontrol does not bring back a reference to the div.

Comment: Remove the wrapping div (the one with the style="display:none").  This is not needed as the query dialog will hide the dialog div until you call it to open.  You should not have to do a find control as the textbox is now attached to the form.  You should be able to get the text on the button click with test.Text .